# Does the React.Children.map function iterate through to the deepest nested children?

Tags: reactjs

```
<MyComponent>
    <div id="first_layer">
        <input id="first_input"/>
        <div id="second_layer">
            <input id="deepest_child"/>
        <div/>
    <div/>
<MyComponent/>
```

Would the Children.map function (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html) get to the "deepest_child" or does immediate children only mean it gets to "first_layer"? How would you get to the deepest child if not?

Comment: it does not traverse nested children

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Comment: There are very few, if any, situations where you would be "getting" elements / components. there's a very good chance a simpler more elegant solution exists to your problem

Comment: I'm trying to pass a prop value "showInput=true" or "showInput=false" to each of the input children of <MyComponent/> @azium

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to transverse the nested children. Assume you have this array of nested objects:

```
const children = [
  {
    id: 1.1,
    secondLayer: {
      id: 1.2,
      deepestLayer: {
        id: 1.3
      }
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2.1,
    secondLayer: {
      id: 2.2,
      deepestLayer: {
        id: 2.3
      }
    }
  },
  {
    id: 3.1,
    secondLayer: {
      id: 3.2,
      deepestLayer: {
        id: 3.3
      }
    }
  }
]
```

By just accessing each object's properties you can obtain all information you need:

**Code:**

```
children.map(nestedObj =>
  <div id={nestedObj.id}>
    <div id={nestedObj.secondLayer.id}>
      <div id={nestedObj.secondLayer.deepestLayer.id}>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

**Result:**

```
<div id="1.1">
  <div id="1.2">
    <div id="1.3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="2.1">
  <div id="2.2">
    <div id="2.3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="3.1">
  <div id="3.2">
    <div id="3.3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see it could get pretty hard to read and comprehend if the structure is too complicated.

---

#### You can also consider destructuring the children first:

**A flatten function:**

```
const flatten = children => (
  children.map(child =>{
    const {
      id: firstLayerId, //rename id
      secondLayer: {
        id: secondLayerId, //rename id
        deepestLayer: {
          id: deepestLayerId //rename id
        }
      }
    } = child

    return ({firstLayerId, secondLayerId, deepestLayerId})
  })
)
```

Here we iterate through children array, and for each nested object we destructure them, and *rename* the `id` accordingly. Then we return a new 1-d object!
And the result is:

**Result:**

```
[
  { firstLayerId: 1.1, secondLayerId: 1.2, deepestLayerId: 1.3 },
  { firstLayerId: 2.1, secondLayerId: 2.2, deepestLayerId: 2.3 },
  { firstLayerId: 3.1, secondLayerId: 3.2, deepestLayerId: 3.3 }
]
```

The new result is so much better to deal with, right?

[Read up on destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: How would this method look for less uniformly structured code? For example, sometimes the "input" element I'm trying to get to will be only one layer deep. Other times it may be 3 layers deep. Ultimately, I am trying to pass a prop (like showInput=true) to every input element in a MyComponent instance